# sumar los numeros pares de los vectores, alguien que me ayude?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, condiciones

necesito poder sumar los valores pares de los vectores. Alguien me puede decir que le falla o falta a mí código.

```
int[] numR = new int [5];
int par = 0;
int suma = 0;
    
for(int i=0; i<numR.length; i++) {
    System.out.println((int)(Math.random()*30));
        
    if ( i %2==0){
        suma = i + par;
            
    }
        
}
System.out.println("La suma de los pares son: " + suma);
```

Comment: En lugar de `suma = i + par;` deberías sumar solo el número actual, probablemente `suma += i;` Lee sobre el operador [addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment), en inglés, pero fácil de entender.

Comment: Hola, podrías hacernos saber si te sirvieron las respuestas dadas

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo la operación con el índice y no con el valor.

cambia esto en tu código.

```
if ( i %2==0){
    suma = i + par;
        
}
```

Por esto

```
 if (numR[i]%2 ==0){
        suma += numR[i];
 }
```

- **i** = índice
- **numR[i]**= valor en la posición dada por el índice **i**

Answer (score 0):

```
int suma = 0;
int[] numR = new int[5];

for(int i = 0; i<numR.length;i++)
{
   numR[i] = (int)(Math.random()*30);
   System.out.println(numR[i]);

   suma = (numR[i]%2 == 0) ?
           suma + numR[i] :
           suma;
}

System.out.println("La suma es " + suma);
```

Primero declaramos la variable suma y el arreglo, posteriormente hacemos un ciclo y dentro de ese ciclo generamos un número aleatorio que será guardado en la posición actual del arreglo, preguntamos si ese número es par, de ser par se aumenta este número par a la variable suma de no ser par pues la variable suma sigue teniéndo el mismo valor, posteriormente cuando termina el ciclo se muestra el resultado de esta suma